# How do I copy a 2d array into a temporary 2d array and return it?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind, memcpy

I'm trying to copy a 2-d array of ints to a temporary 2-d array of ints and return it. I've had a go at it below, but I get a pretty suspicious malloc error. I tried inspecting it with valgrind, but couldn't find anything useful

```
int **get_grid_state(int **grid, int height, int length) {
    int **grid_state;
    int i;

    grid_state = malloc(height * sizeof(int*));

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        grid_state[i] = malloc(length);
        memcpy(grid_state[i], grid[i], length);
    }
    return grid_state;
}
```

Un-settling error message is as follows:

```
program: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted
```

Comment: There is **no** 2D array, nothing which can represent one or point to one. If you want a 2D array, **use one**! Then a simple `memcpy` is sufficient.

Comment: --> `for ( i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                    grid_state[i] = malloc(length*sizeof(int));

                    memcpy(grid_state[i], grid[i], length*sizeof(int));
            }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Indeed.  But it's unclear that explains the OP's issue (he/she is allocating `length` and copying `length`, so it's consistent).

Comment: unless `length` is <= 0 ? is that allowed to malloc 0 or less?

Comment: @noobatrilla did you solve the problem and if yes, what was the cause?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `malloc` takes a `size_t`, so it cannot be negative.

Comment: ok, what if you pass a negative integer ? how is it converted to unsigned?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the cause was me being silly and not mallocing enough space ie. (length*sizeof(int)) doh, ty again.

Comment: @noobatrilla did you post the right code? because the code above is functionnaly wrong but would not do that as Oliver Charlesworth stated.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - yea pasted the right code. Why isn't it right to allocate the length then memcpy it into the the row?

Comment: you malloc `length` not `length*sizeof(int)` but you copy the same amount so it should not crash, just provide wrong data for the last elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct, except for the size `length` in the inner loop: it should `length * sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(**grid)`:

```
        grid_state[i] = malloc(length * sizeof(**grid));
        memcpy(grid_state[i], grid[i], length * sizeof(**grid));
```

The cause for the *unsettling* error is the subarrays are allocated too small and you probably modify them in some other part of the program, causing some corruption of the `malloc` internal data that is detected at some later call to one of the allocation functions: `malloc()`, `free()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`...

Note also that you do not check the return values of these `malloc()` calls. If for some reason `malloc` cannot allocate the memory, you will invoke undefined behavior instead of returning `NULL` gracefully.